# In general, is the probability density the same as the $|G|^2$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics

For a (non-relativistic) propagator $G(x,t,x_0,t_0)$, is $|G(x,t)|^2=\rho(x,t)=\psi^*(x,t)\psi(x,t)$ true?

I'm wondering about this, since I could use the propagator to find the probability density from the relation with the wavefunction:
\begin{equation}
\psi(x,t)=\int dx_0 G(x,t,x_0,t_0)\psi(x_0,t_0)
\end{equation}
and thus for the probability density i would end up with a double integral to relate it with the propagator, so I don't see how $|G(x,t)|^2=\rho(x,t)$. Yet I have seen in books like *Quantum field theory for the Gifted Amateur*, of Tom Lancaster that say that, and (more explicitly) in this page

http://galileo.phys.virginia.edu/classes/751.mf1i.fall02/Propagator.htm

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

The propagator $G(x,t; x_0, t_0)$ gives you the probability amplitude to have a particle at $x_0$ and $t_0$ travels to $x$ at $t$. To link with the density, you need to look at $x_0 = x$ and $t_0 = t$. So I think what is meant by $|G(x,t)|^2$ is $G(x,t) \equiv G(x,t+0^+; x,t)$. This gives you the number of the amplitude probability to find a particle at $x$ and $t$, which is the density.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I am not asking what $|G(x,t)|^2$ means. I think your reply has flaws, the amplitude is not the same as the probability density, you should have read the link before replying; $|G(x,t)|^2$ actually stands for $ G^*(x,t;x_0,t_0) G(x,t;x_0,t_0) $, I didn't put the  dependence on $x_0$, $t_0$  just for the notation to coincide with $\rho(x,t)$.

Comment: @user162485 this answer suggests that given that you already established with 100% probability that at time $t_0$ your particle was at $x_0$, $|G|^2$ is precisely the probability of finding it at $x$ at time $t$. In the general case, the propagator describes how your initial wavefunction evolves into the final wavefunction. The probability is then equal to the absolute-value-squared of the final wavefunction, as always.

Comment: @user162485 and in the general case – you are right indeed, there's a double integral. This is called interference.